# STM32 enabling clock for port C sets IDR bit 1

Tags: stm32, arm, nucleo

Why does enabling the clock for port C set the IDR bit 1?
It's the configuration for a Nucleo-F767ZI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode of the pin is as an input, as soon as you enable the peripherals clock (well, a few clock cycles later), the pins state is clocked into the IDR.

Something is making that pin high.

As a comment on your code, there are defines for the bit positions in the registers, probably provided in the same include as you're getting the `RCC` pointer from, `RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;` is more readable than `RCC->AHB1ENR |= 4;`

Answer (score 1):

The pin is connected to something that makes the pin voltage to be high enough for the pin to read as logic 1, but state cannot be read until peripheral clock is enabled so it will read logic 1 only after enabling the clock.